# How can I RaiseEvent in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, raiseevent

I have 2 project in my Solution. 
Lets say Proj A and Proj B.

Proj A is having my custom event. and same Proj is Raising that event using RaiseEvent Function of Vb.net And Proj B is having reference of Proj A.  
Proj B is adding handler for Proj A's custom event.

but my custom event cant raise. 
Could any one can explain me how can I do that.?

Edit:

Proj A

```
Public Shared Event cardReadComplete(ByVal data As String)
 Public Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As Windows.Forms.Keys) 
  IO.File.AppendAllText("E:\log.log", Key.ToString() & vbCrLf)
 RaiseEvent cardReadComplete(encryptedData)
End Sub
```

Proj B

```
 Private Sub handleSwipeCardRequest(ByVal msgText As String)
        AddHandler CardReader.Main.cardReadComplete, AddressOf sendSwipeCardDetails
        CardReader.Main.cardReadComplete()
End Sub
```

I am calling handleSwipeCardRequest function first and then Raising its event.

Comment: Have you declared the variable that holds the instance of whichever type it is in Proj A using the WithEvents keyword? Please post some sample code.

Comment: You seem to mixing up the Sub and the Event name.  And it looks like you'll have to press a key to trigger the event.  Although it is a KeyDown event without the Handles keyword so it probably never fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event will be raised when `kbHook_KeyDown` gets called, assuming it gets called after the `AddHandler` line is executed. Are you sure that the KeyDown function gets called? As Hans Passant said, you might be missing a Handles keyword:

```
Public Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
    ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
AddHandler kbHook.KeyDown , AddressOf Me.kbHook_KeyDown
```